# Play framework WAR file won't deploy on tomcat7

Tags: tomcat7, playframework-1.x

I created a Play framework v1.2.5 web service and I've successfully deployed it as a WAR file on Tomcat 7.0.30. It's been working fine for months.

I recently tweaked the code a tiny bit (I literally added trim() to 2 functions). Tested it. It works. I generated a new WAR but it consistently fails to start on the server.

The catalina logs say: geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

but I tried removing the jar as previous posts suggest but it's still not working. Others have suggested it is a memory problem. I asked my sysAdmin to increase the memory but he hasn't done it yet.

Am I on the right track or is there another solution?

Comment: At first sight this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502239/playframework-tomcat-deployment-issue looks a lot like your problem, can you check please?

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I tried removing the jar. no luck. I'm 98% sure I can't use a different version of tomcat.

Comment: I increased the memory. No luck. it's still complaining about the geronimo jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! I noticed that the Tomcat 7 server was using an older version of Java.

I had my sys admin upgrade to JDK 1.7x and the darn WAR started working again. That still doesn't explain why it stopped working in the first place.

And yes, the Play 1.2.5 documentation says it only works on tomcat 6x but my company won't roll back to 6.