# mvn tomcat7:run-war or tomcat:run-war give a 404 and no logs

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have one problem wich make me crazy :

I have one maven project , (**play2** application in maven project with `play2war` plugin)

when I launch mvn `tomcat7:run-war` or `tomcat:run-war` (i change the servlet container) this is the rsult :

```
    [INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8090/arhswfe
    [INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration atC:\dev\projects\publicwebsite\sources\arhsweb\frontend\target\tomcat
    [INFO] create webapp with contextPath: /arhswfe
    Nov 08, 2013 4:30:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
    Nov 08, 2013 4:30:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Tomcat
    Nov 08, 2013 4:30:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
    Nov 08, 2013 4:30:55 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
    WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/Logger'.
   Nov 08, 2013 4:30:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
   INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
```

all seems to be ok but when I test on `url` it give me a `404` and `no logs`,
in a standalone server it is ok.

Have you got any idea? I have configured all it is possible :

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <tomcatLoggingFile>D:/log.txt</tomcatLoggingFile>
            <warDirectory>${project.build.directory}</warDirectory>
            <update>true</update>
            <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
            <port>8090</port>
            <warFile>arhswfe.war</warFile>
            <ignorePackaging>true</ignorePackaging>
            <contextFile>../configuration/context.xml</contextFile>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

logs always empty no error but `` `404.... ``

Comment: [Probably this will resolve your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502239/playframework-tomcat-deployment-issue)

Comment: No it solves not my problem, when i take my war and deploy it in a standalone tomcat it is OK, i use playframework2.1.4 and only commands             mvn tomcat:run-war give me a 404 page and no logs or mvn tomcat7:run-war it makes me crazy 2 days spent on this...

Answer (score 1):

For logging add in plugin configuration this part

```
               <extraDependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.17</version>
                    </dependency>
                </extraDependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you i finish this task can we closed the discussion???? thanks for the </etra-dependencies> but with play framework it is better to use logback instead log4J because the librairies are in package by default...

Comment: I put logback in extra dependencies and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

use `<path>/</path>` tag so your configuration becomes:

```
       <configuration>
            <tomcatLoggingFile>D:/log.txt</tomcatLoggingFile>
            <warDirectory>${project.build.directory}</warDirectory>
            <update>true</update>
            <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
            <port>8090</port>
            **<path>/</path>**
            <warFile>arhswfe.war</warFile>
            <ignorePackaging>true</ignorePackaging>
            <contextFile>../configuration/context.xml</contextFile>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: thank you but i tried already and no possibilité, so with tomcat 6 it is not possible to do it, with tomcat 7 it is ok thanks, i have no tell it was ok....